# Data Driven test framework in c# + NUnit

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

I am required to create a data driven test framework in c# at my work place. I have been given time to get to grips with c# since the little experience I have is mostly in java. Basically the framework will work with:

- Selenium WebDriver
- NUnit test framework
- c#

I have been able to create tests successfully and ran them via NUnit GUI. Thats fine. The bit am lost is how to pull test parameters from an external file (either a database table or excel). Preferably a database table.

For example I want to store parameters like xpaths, urls, test data in this table and then reference them in my tests. In this way, I dont have to edit code or hard code parameters in my test. I just pull from the database.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Work on that answer rate buddy. How you implement this depends on how you interact with your database at the moment, in the application you are testing? LINQ2SQL? Entity Framework? Pure SQL statements?